# Passing parameter from parent to custom control WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm writing a custom DateTimePicker class for WPF, but I can't seem to get the binding values from parent.

Parent:

```
<cc:DateTimePicker DTSelectedDate="{Binding RA_EFFECTIVE_DATE}" />
```

Child:

```
public partial class DateTimePicker : UserControl
{



    public DateTime DTSelectedDate  { get; set; }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
            "DTSelectedDate", 
            typeof(DateTime),
            typeof(DateTimePicker)
    );



    public DateTimePicker()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;


    }

}
```

Child XAML:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DTSelectedDate}" Width="150"/>
```

I stopped with the debugger in the constructor, but can't seem to get any values from parent.

Comment: DTSelectedDate in getter/setter you need to return DTSelectedDate DP.

Comment: Take a look at dependency property syntax (http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html#creation). Your DTSelectedDate property needs to utilise the GetValue and SetValue methods. Also check the naming conventions for your two properties - the dependency property name should match the "regular" property name but suffixed with "Property", i.e. "DTSelectedDateProperty".

Comment: Tried it both, with getter: GetValue(DTSelectedDateProperty) , setter: SetValue(DTSelectedDateProperty, value) and renaming the depndency property. Still no effect, thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimePicker));

public DateTime SelectedDate
{
    get { return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value); }
}
```

Also edit your child XAML:

```
<UserControl
           // the usual stuff that is already there
    x:Name="Me">

<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=SelectedDate}"
```

...

Comment: The problem isn't within the child XAML, i can programmatically set values of SelectedDate inside child XAML. The problem is that the parent XAML doesn't set SelectedDate value.